# How can I convert from TXT into XML in VBA or Visual Studio?

Tags: xml, parsing, vba, excel

Is there any code in VBA or Visual Studio that will convert txt files into xml.

I need to parse simple txt file with columns into XML file.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Please read the [guide to asking a good question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) and show [what you have tried](http://whatyouhavetried.com).

Comment: Are the values in the txt file delimited or something??? How would one  know the mapping of text to xml element????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Text to Columns` feature of the `Data` ribbon to convert delimited text into columns.

This article, http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/create-an-xml-data-file-and-xml-schema-file-from-worksheet-data-HA010342365.aspx , outlines a process for saving XML from an Excel Worksheet.